# Why create Collections if we already have Collection?

Tags: java, collections

So I know that Collections is a utility class and Collection is a base interface. However, I still don't understand why couldn't the methods in Collections just be put into Collection? Is it just to make things easier?

Are there differences between methods within Collections and Collection? Maybe some of the methods are implemented differently by different Collections? And thus for more universal methods, they got thrown into the utility class Collections?

I guess I am just curious how do you decide what get thrown into Collections or Collections for developers? Could anyone provide some examples of these?

Comment: I am curious why can't you put the method from Collections into Collection(like .sort()). How do developers decide that some methods stay in Collection to be specifically implemented by different collections such as ArrayList, or that some other methods will be put into Collections to be universally used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Collection is an interface. It defines the contract that all classes implementing Collection must obey: have a `size()` method, have an `iterator()` method, etc.

Collections is a utility class, containing methods related to various collection implementations: creating an empty Set, transforming any list into a synchronized list, etc. These are methods that do not belong to a collection: it would be stupid to have to create a new collection in order to be able to create an empty set, wouldn't it?

Now, with Java 8, all those static methods could be static methods of the Collection interface. But

- this is too late to be done, because Collections exists since Java 2
- there are so many of them that they are best kept separate, in order to avoid cluttering the Collection interface, and make it less understandable.

Note, however, that since Java 8, some (or at least one) of those static utility methods became an instance method, thanks to the possibility of having default methods: you can now sort a list using `list.sort(comparator)`, rather than using `Collections.sort(list, comparator)`. Of course, `Collections.sort()` still exists: removing it would break millions of existing programs.

Comment: thank you so much. This is exactly the answer I am looking for.